# ES6 How to convert key, value pair to string recursively in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, key-value

I try to interpolate error messages, because I need it in a special text format.
Whats the best practice doing that nowadays :)
thanks for any help!

http://codepen.io/radosch/pen/wWYPYG?editors=1111

**desired outcome:**

```
Password longer then 5 chars \n
Email has invalid format \n
```

**Source:**

```
let data = {
  "errors": [
    {
      "password": "must min have 5 characters"
    },
    {
      "email": "has invalid format"
    }
  ]
}
```

**possible solution:**

```
let res = data.errors.map(function(error, index) {
  let keyName = Object.keys(error)
  let str = error[keyName]
  return keyName + " " + str ;
});

console.log(res.join("\n"));
```

Comment: *nowdays* how you want? Your question is unclear. Please define the problem.

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array. They you are trying to use that array as an index into `error`?

Comment: OT Personal: @BhojendraNepal what Problem exactly do you have. Downrate?
As you can read below, its a Problem just hacking without knowing whats best practice right now. You could be more constructive but only criticize and downvote. Thats embarassing and not nice for newcommers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that ES6 functions are **very** slow (at least on nodejs) ([but not only](https://kpdecker.github.io/six-speed/#)), so I would still use ES5 functions, like

```
var res = '';
for (let i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(data.errors[i])[0];
  res += key + ' ' + data.errors[i][key] + '/n';
}
```

Benchmark:

```
question x 189,765 ops/sec ±1.39% (82 runs sampled)
maxx answer x 267,565 ops/sec ±0.98% (80 runs sampled)
for keys x 1,735,444 ops/sec ±0.85% (82 runs sampled)
Fastest is for keys
```

The test:

```
"use strict";
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

suite
.add('map', function() {
let data = {
  "errors": [
    {
      "password": "must min have 5 characters"
    },
    {
      "email": "has invalid format"
    }
  ]
}

let res = data.errors.map(function(error, index) {
  let keyName = Object.keys(error)
  let str = error[keyName]
  return keyName + " " + str ;
});
res = res.join("\n");
})
.add('maxx answer', function() {
let data = {
  "errors": [
    {
      "password": "must min have 5 characters"
    },
    {
      "email": "has invalid format"
    }
  ]
}
data.errors.map(error => Object.keys(error).map(key => `${key} ${error[key]}`)).join('\n');

})
.add('for keys', function() {
let data = {
  "errors": [
    {
      "password": "must min have 5 characters"
    },
    {
      "email": "has invalid format"
    }
  ]
}

var res = '';
for (let i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(data.errors[i])[0];
  res += key + ' ' + data.errors[i][key] + '/n';
}
})
// add listeners
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
// run async
.run({ 'async': true });
```

Comment: omg, thats a great answer! 
Thnx a lot!
unfortunately its like always, you trade performance for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
data.errors.map(error => Object.keys(error).map(key => `${key} ${error[key]}`)).join('\n');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! 
although I use it with multiline, for better readability